# FT232 - no ttyUSB* device will be created after plugin

Tags: 16.04, tty, serial-port

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I connect the PC with the `FT232R` on a `DE10 Standard`, the system recognizes the `FT232R`. But in the /dev directory is no ttyUSB* file created after plugin, not even a new tty* file was created.

I want to communicate via serial console between the PC and the `FT232R`. What do I have to do to make this work?

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC

$ dmesg | tail
[12107.165325] usb 1-2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[12107.165329] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[12107.165332] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: A106I6UW
[12141.041280] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 12
[12146.727974] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[12146.881737] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[12146.881742] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[12146.881747] usb 1-2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[12146.881750] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[12146.881754] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: A106I6UW

$ journalctl --follow

Jul 12 10:11:29 OL kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
Jul 12 10:11:29 OL kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
Jul 12 10:11:29 OL kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 12 10:11:29 OL kernel: usb 1-2: Product: FT232R USB UART
Jul 12 10:11:29 OL kernel: usb 1-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
Jul 12 10:11:29 OL kernel: usb 1-2: SerialNumber: A106I6UW
Jul 12 10:11:29 OL mtp-probe[15560]: checking bus 1, device 13: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Jul 12 10:11:29 OL mtp-probe[15560]: bus: 1, device: 13 was not an MTP device

$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory
```

The user is in the `dialout` group.

EDIT:
`module-init-tools` have been installed.

```
$ sudo modprobe -v usbserial vendor=0x0403 product=0x6001
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-54-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko vendor=0x0403 product=0x6001
```

Comment: `sudo modprobed -v usbserial vendor=0x0403 product=0x6001` please.

Comment: @nobody I wrote the result of the modprobe as EDIT in the Question. Which information provides this command that can help to find the answer?

Comment: I wanted to know if the modul is present. Any changes in `/dev/ `?  Or in the output `lsusb` ?

Comment: @nobody As you can see, it is now present.
`ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*`
`crw-rw---- 1 root users 188, 0 Jul 12 12:35 /dev/ttyUSB0`
Would you like to the naswer the Question?

Comment: No, because the answer would not be complete. I have no idea why it is not loaded automatic. This should be triggert by udev.

Comment: @nobody I had to install `module-init-tools` package to execute the command you provided. As far as I understand /udev relies on modprobe to load drivers for the automatically detected hardware. I think that's the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case is that the `fdti_sio` module is blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

To resolve the problem remove/comment the line `blacklist ftdi_sio` in the `blacklist.conf` file to load this module while booting or load the module with:

```
sudo modprobe ftdi_sio
sudo modprobe usbserial
```